# alpine linux do not execute compiled nodejs

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I'm trying to set up my docker file without success.

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
FROM alpine:3.5
ENV VERSION=4.8.1 
RUN apk add --no-cache curl make gcc g++ python linux-headers binutils-gold gnupg libstdc++ tar xz && \
    curl -sSL -o node.tar.xz https://nodejs.org/download/release/v${VERSION}/node-v${VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.xz && \
    tar xJf node.tar.xz -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 
CMD ["node", "--version"]
```

what I get as response is this:

```
Step 1 : FROM alpine:3.5
 ---> 4a415e366388
Step 2 : ENV VERSION 4.8.1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 69c1a9ea15a9
Step 3 : RUN apk add --no-cache curl make gcc g++ python linux-headers binutils-gold gnupg libstdc++ tar xz &&  curl -sSL -o node.tar.xz https://nodejs.org/download/release/v${VERSION}/node-v${VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.xz &&   tar xJf node.tar.xz -C /usr/local --strip-components 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7f508d49e0bc
Step 4 : CMD node --version
 ---> Running in 196a2ed982fd
 ---> c0e1fbc1fe23
Removing intermediate container 196a2ed982fd
Successfully built c0e1fbc1fe23
+ docker -H tcp://tjsu250n:2375 run --restart=always --name=barcode -d -p 9002:9001 tjdft_gesirh/barcode:194
c8483a53359d8a26b2f7e3e3bd01b3185a235f7722687f3aadf9c4ff6d4ac540
+ docker -H tcp://tjsu250n:2375 images -a
+ grep tjdft_gesirh/barcode
+ expr 194 - 1
+ awk {print $1}
+ grep 193
+ [ !=  ]
/tmp/hudson6046350871523920710.sh: 14: [: !=: unexpected operator
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But despite of that message, the command **docker logs xpto**  returns:

```
standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

if I use **RUN** command to run this:

```
RUN ls -la /usr/local/bin/ && \     
    echo $PATH && \
    npm --version
```

I get this as response:

```
Step 4 : RUN ls -la /usr/local/bin/ &&  echo $PATH &&   npm --version &&    ./usr/local/bin/node --version
 ---> Running in 1b6bd429d169
total 24244
drwxrwxr-x    2 500      500             27 Mar 21 19:14 .
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root           101 Mar 23 21:02 ..
-rwxrwxr-x    1 500      500       24825844 Mar 21 19:14 node
lrwxrwxrwx    1 500      500             38 Mar 21 19:14 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[91m/usr/local/bin/npm: exec: line 2: /usr/local/bin/node: not found
[0mtime="2017-03-23T18:12:59-03:00" level=info msg="The command '/bin/sh -c ls -la /usr/local/bin/ && \techo $PATH && \tnpm --version && \t./usr/local/bin/node --version' returned a non-zero code: 127" 
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I need some help.

**## Edit ##**

The error `/usr/local/bin/node: not found` occurred with oracle java too. Don't know why it is not executable from alpine.

Comment: You have a nodejs 4.8.1 alpine dockerfile [here](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/14681db8e89c0493e8af20657883fa21488a7766/4.8/alpine/Dockerfile) available under `node:4.8.1-alpine`

Comment: I need to install nodejs on a alpine-oraclejdk8 dockerfile image. :(

Comment: does the Dockerfile build locally, without jenkins?

Comment: @lang2 I don't have local docker installed..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to build node on alpine due to [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/).

See the official [7.7 alpine Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/6f9f865df604e72ad2cabe2d78ab12c8f61640cb/7.7/alpine/Dockerfile) that does a build compared to the [7.7 Debian Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/6f9f865df604e72ad2cabe2d78ab12c8f61640cb/7.7/Dockerfile) which uses the pre built package.

Alpine also do [`nodejs` apk packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) but they won't be as up to date as the release on [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org).

Comment: I have tried the ./configure command, but it is not present on node source installation...

Comment: Are you sure you're downloading the source tar ball instead of the release? `configure` is in https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.1/node-v6.10.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `apk` to download nodejs. Package details can be found [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/nodejs)

```
apk add nodejs
```

should install nodejs 6.10.1-r0.

Although building from source can be fun and challenging! Examples can be found [here](https://github.com/mhart/alpine-node) and [here](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node)

Hope that helps!